# dateadd in Redshift not compensating for leap year

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dateadd

I'm working on a YoY self join to see sales this year's and last year's sales numbers side by side in the same table.

The query looks something like this:

```
Select a.date_column, a.sales_column as ty_sales, b.sales_column as ly_sales

from sales_table a

left join sales_table b

on (dateadd(year, -1, a.date_column)) = b.date_column
```

This in theory should be fine, the problem is that 2016-02-29 records are joining to 2015-03-01 records, which is causing the numbers to be off for 02-2016.

Is this a known issue with redshift/postgres?

Let me know if I can provide any additional clarity.

Comment: Why did you tag this wih mysql, sql and postgresql when it has nothing to do with those?

Comment: It's a SQL related question, postgresql syntax is fairly synonymous with redshift, and MySQL for visibility. Because chances are if a person is familiar with MySQL he or she is probably familiar with postgres/redshift.

Comment: @masdawg . . . The "sql" tag provides visibility.  You should only tag with the database you are actually using and not extraneous databases.

Comment: Duly noted. Do either of you have any insight into the question?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that it's a "known issue", it's how they decided to handle leap years. When you compare 2/29 for YoY, which day would you like to compare it with? If you compare it with 2/28 then are you also going to compare 2/28 of this year with 2/28 of last year? You're now comparing two days to the same day. Then you have to account for potentially double-counting those sales from last year when you total things up.

The short of it is that you need to come up with very specific business rules on how you want to handle leap years when it comes to reporting and then implement those rules, being careful to test them thoroughly given that date functions are often a bit arbitrary (for any database/language) when it comes to leap years.